# The UISelectMany value should be an array or a collection type, the actual type is java.lang.String

Tags: jsf

I have a selectmanylistbox filled with List and i got the error `"Target model Type is no a Collection or Array"` (and `"The UISelectMany value should be an array or a collection type, the actual type is java.lang.String"` in the console) when i try to submit my form despite i am using a collection ...

Thank you very much for your help

jsf page :

```
<td>People list</td>
<td>
    <h:selectManyListbox value=" #{people.selectedPeople}" size="3">
        <f:selectItems value="#{people.peopleList}"/>
    </h:selectManyListbox>
</td>
```

My managed bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="people")
@RequestScoped

public class People implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<String> peopleList;
    private List<String> selectedPeople;


    public People(){        
        peopleList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    }

    // getters , setters
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `<h:selectManyListbox>` your value should be an array of Strings. JSF doesn't like using Lists for that, for some odd reason.  I know this because I just had a similar problem the other day with a `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` in PrimeFaces.

If you change from `private List<String> selectedPeople;` to `private String[] selectedPeople;` (and change the getters and setters as necessary) it should work.

EDIT: Failing that, I just noticed that you have a space in `value=" #{people.selectedPeople}"` which may also be part of the problem.

Comment: damn , the space was the problem .... I was so focused about the List type and i didn t checked about jsf form. Thank you very much anyway . Sorry for wasting your time for a such pitiful problem

Comment: Hey, it's no problem. I've asked stupid questions here before too, and sometimes it is actually as simple as missing an extra space in your own code.